# Can't use my windows profile: "We can't sign in to your account"

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles, system-restore

When I tried to use my computer today while turning it on it showed me (only) the we can't sign error, which is one of the two errros presented in my picture.

I tried a few things but none worked. I also tried system restore, I used a few different restore points and so I got these errors, the "we can't sign.." and the other one, which is a about the restore points saying "System restore failed while restoring the directory from the restore point.".

I don't know what to do, everytime I turn on the computer it's "preparing windows" which takes a few minutes every time and creates a temporary profile, I can't access my personal files, and I can't even restore it.

Any suggestions?

[image: Windows signing and System restore errors picture]

Answer (score 0):

Some manipulations that you could try :

- Try to system restore again with an earlier system restore point
- Try using [Reprofiler](https://www.iwrconsultancy.co.uk/reprofiler.htm)
  described
  [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-windows-user-profile-data-settings-with-reprofiler),
  after reading attentively the accompanying text
- If you are comfortable with using regedit and modifying the registry,
  try the advice in the following articles :

[You’ve been signed in with a Temporary Profile error in Windows](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/you-ve-been-signed-in-with-a-temporary-profile)

[Fix “We can’t sign into your account” error in Windows 10 AU](https://errorfixer.co/cant-sign-into-account-windows-10-anniversary-update/)