# Windows resetting all the data everytime I sign in

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-profiles

I recently got into a strange and weird problem with windows 10. When I booted my pc today, It, as usual, asked for my pin and on Welcome screen, It showed the "Preparing Windows..."message. It was strange but I waited for it to end. And as it ended, I could see that my desktop background is changed to default windows 10 background, There are only few apps on my desktop, My taskbar now only has 4 default apps pinned. In short, Everything was reset.

Well, I quickly just searched through internet and found a thread on answers.microsoft.com. It was referring to the same problem as me. It did give me an idea regarding the problem though answers weren't prominent.

**The problem is apparently with the profiles**. When I go to my "Downloads" folder there's literally nothing there. All other default folders, like Documents, Pictures, Videos have nothing in them. I went to the `C:\Users\` and I saw there's a new folder named `TMP`. It had all default folders. i.e Downloads, Pictures, Videos etc. I could see my main profile folder in `C:\Users`. When I open it I see all the downloads I had in downloads folder and everything is normal there.

When my PC boots up, It said "Unable to sign in to your Microsoft account. Please sign out and sign in again"

All Windows apps aren't working, nor is the Start menu. I can't open Settings. When I click on the window app like settings, nothing happens. Same for Start menu.

All my apps are at the place. On desktop. All system icons like Control Panel are gone.

I also have Ubuntu dual booted which works fine but the Windows 10 drives are into read only mode for some reason.

Comment: Go here:  https://account.microsoft.com/account   Log in and if you need to, use Forgot Password. Reset your account here and then restart your computer and log in again.

Comment: Hi @John. I did that. Apparently, My default (main) user profile has got corrupted or something else which I'm not aware of how. Would you suggest a fix for that?

Comment: The process to replace the User Profile has a number of steps and I posted an answer. You will need to see where your data is.

Comment: Some potential options here: https://superuser.com/questions/1314611/cant-use-my-windows-profile-we-cant-sign-in-to-your-account

Answer (score 0):

Summary from question and comments:  "My default (main) user profile has got corrupted"

You need to replace the User Profile with a working Profile. Most Windows Repairs will not repair a damaged Windows User Profile.

**You must make a new User Profile.**

(a) Log in as yourself. Make a good copy in a secure (non-User) location and back up all documents, data and email, and also favorites if you have many favorites.

**Note:** You may need to look in c:\Users to see where your data is and take ownership of it.

(b) Assuming this current but damaged User is a member of Administrators, make a new Windows User Account and make it a member of Administrators. You will need this second Admin user.

(c) Log in as the new administrator account. Go to Advanced System settings and make a copy of the damaged profile. Locate the profile backup in the same folder as you established for your data.

(d) Now I assume you want the new User to have the same name as the damaged one. So then you now need to delete the damaged profile. Be certain you have all your backups.

(e) Delete the user id of the damaged profile and then make a new user with the same name. Make this a member of Administrators. You can collect your data and email from the temporary saved location.

(f) Log in as the new user, and set it up. Most apps will need to be run under the new user.

You may wish to thoroughly review the steps a couple of times.

Once you are ready, start in and create the new User and Profile.